# How to call method with for loop in another method?

Tags: graphics, processing, papplet

I am printing objects from an array outputting 8 image objects using a for loop, the code works without draw() method, but when I include it, only the background image is shown.

How do I call the draw method in the setup method to work?

```java
public class FishPAppletTest {
  private static PApplet processing;  // PApplet object that represents the graphic interface of the JunglePark application
  private static PImage backgroundImage;  // PImage object that represents the background image
  private static Fish[] fishes;  // fishes object, reference to perfect size array storing fish objects in the fish tank. These fish can be of different species.
  private static Random randGen; // Type random constructor when new, Generator of random numbers
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Utility.startApplication();
    System.out.println(fishes[0]);  //null because it is not stored?
  }

  /**
  * Defines the initial environment properties of this application
  * @param processingObj a reference to the graphic display window of this application
  */
  public static void setup(PApplet processing) {  // PApplet is kept, processing is the variable as input   
    backgroundImage = processing.loadImage("images/background.png");  // loads image in background
    fishes = new Fish[8];
    processing.image(backgroundImage, processing.width / 2, processing.height /2);  // draw background image
  }
      
  /**
  * Draws and updates the application display window.
  * This callback method called in an infinite loop.
  */
  public static void draw() {  // called by utility class
    for (int i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {
      fishes[i] = new Fish(processing, processing.width / 2, processing.height / 2); 
      randGen = new Random();  // WORKS UP
      int x = randGen.nextInt(processing.width);
      int y = randGen.nextInt(processing.height);
      fishes[i] = new Fish(processing, x, y);
      fishes[i].draw();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's [Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info): think of it as a subset of java (or a java library) aimed at artists/designers/creatives.

Comment: No worries at all. It can be a confusing name for a language (usually people think of image/signal processing/etc.).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza My code works without draw() method , how do I make sure it works with it included?

Comment: @EH I'll follow up with an answer shortly. There are quite a few things a bit confusing (such as the need for static properties/method, how is `Fish` implemented, is `Utility.startApplication` required ?)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Two png images are imported for the fish image and background image. Utility is required to start the setup method. java.util.Random; java.io.File; processing.core.PApplet; processing.core.PImage; are also all imported.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what Utility and Fish do, it's hard to guess what the exact behaviour is.

If you're seing the background and not the fish it's likely `setup()` get's called, but not `draw()` for some reason.

Ideally you'd initialise the `Fish` instances once in `setup()` then re-use in `draw()` (otherwise you're instantiating multiple times per second).

I would try something simpler.

```java
public class FishPAppletTest extends PApplet{

  private PImage backgroundImage; // PImage object that represents the background image

  private Fish[] fishes;

   // fishes object, reference to perfect size array storing fish objects in the fish tank. These fish can be of different species.

  public void setup() { 
    // wild guess about sketch dimensions
    size(600, 600);

    backgroundImage = loadImage("images/background.png"); 
    //loads image in background
    
    fishes = new Fish[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {

      fishes[i] = new Fish(this, width / 2, height / 2); 

    }

  }
      
  /**
  * Draws and updates the application display window.
  * This callback method called in an infinite loop.
  */

  public void draw() { 

    image(backgroundImage, width / 2, height /2);

    for (int i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {

    
      // hopefully Fish has public x,y properties ?
      fishes[i].x = (int)random(width);
      fishes[i].y = (int)random(height);
      fishes[i].draw();

    }
   
  }
  // initialise PApplet (kicks off setup/draw Processing sketch lifecycle)
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    PApplet.main(FishPAppletTest.class.getCanonicalName());
    
  }

}
```

and this is a placeholder class mimicking your structure a bit:

```java
public class Fish{

  private PAppet parent;
  public float x, y;

  public Fish(PApplet parent, float x, float y){
    this.parent = parent;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }   

  public void draw(){
    parent.ellipse(x, y, 20, 10);
  }


}
```

Hopefully this helps restructure the program ?
The ingredients are there, the order was a bit off.

FWIW, this is the sketch version you can simply paste and run in the Processing IDE:

```java
// PImage object that represents the background image
private PImage backgroundImage; 

// fishes reference to perfect size array storing fish objects in the fish tank. These fish can be of different species.
private Fish[] fishes;


public void setup() { 
  size(600, 600);
  
  //loads image in background
  backgroundImage = loadImage("images/background.png"); 
  
  fishes = new Fish[8];
  // instantiate Fish once
  for (int i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {

    fishes[i] = new Fish(this, width / 2, height / 2); 

  }

}
    
/**
* Draws and updates the application display window.
* This callback method called in an infinite loop.
*/

public void draw() { 

  image(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
  
  // reuse Fish instances
  for (int i = 0; i < fishes.length; i++) {

    // hopefully Fish has public x,y properties ?
    fishes[i].x = (int)random(width);
    fishes[i].y = (int)random(height);
    fishes[i].draw();

  }
 
}

public class Fish{

  private PApplet parent;
  public float x, y;

  public Fish(PApplet parent, float x, float y){
    this.parent = parent;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }   

  public void draw(){
    parent.ellipse(x, y, 20, 10);
  }


}
```